# SOQL Query for changes in any custom/standard objects then we need to know those changes

Tags: soql

For objects we have to do for metadata level. Say for ex: If any changes in any custom/standard objects then we need to know those changes.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/366524/edit) your question to add what you have tried (it's OK if it fails) and how it is not working (e.g., *exact* error text). This site exists to *help*, not do the work. (From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center: *"We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services."*) Please read more of the Help Center, and also take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about metadata (as opposed to data stored in a field on a record of a particular SObject, for which a trigger or Change Data Capture would be used), **SOQL cannot do this** (capturing changes in the SObject metadata such as adding/removing/changing fields).

Going even further, Salesforce in general doesn't provide us with any tooling to detect such changes when they happen. This may be possible to an extent with an Apex class through a combination of implementing the `schedulable` interface, `schema.getGlobalDescribe()`, and custom metadata types.

If you're trying to do this to enable some sort of change policy, there's likely a better (and easier) way to go about that (tightly controlling who is given admin access to your org, requiring docmentation for work performed, perhaps sfdx and git to help you find changes after they happen, etc...)